# vscode debugging: launch program prior to attaching to it

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am developing a plugin for some program in C#. In order to debug my plugin, I need to

1. start the program,
2. attach the debugger to the program.

**How do I do 1.?**

My `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "net48",
            "type": "clr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processName":"sldworks.exe",
        }
    ]
}
```

When I start debugging, I get the (expected) message that no process with the specified name was found.

So I tried adding

```
"preLaunchTask": "C:\myPath\sldworks.exe"
```

into the `configuration`, but then VScode says

> Could not find the task 'C:\myPath\sldworks.exe'.

I double-checked that the path is correct, and if I copy it into `cmd` and hit ENTER, the program starts.

Comment: I thought the tasks were defined in `tasks.json` and the name of that task is what you put in `preLaunchTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @DavidG's hint I was able to figure it out. I had some issues with spaces in the command but was able to resolve this as well.

`launch.json:`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "net48",
            "type": "clr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processName":"sldworks.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "runSwx"
        }
    ]
}
```

`tasks.json:`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "runSwx",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:/'Program Files'/'SOLIDWORKS Corp'/SOLIDWORKS/sldworks.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```